# GridView not showing items with custom adapter

Tags: android, gridview

I'm using a `GridView` and a custom adapter (`MenuAdapter`) to show some texts and images, but when I launch the activity, it doesn't show the items.

**MenuAdapter:**

```
private Context mContext;
private final String[] gridViewString;
private final int[] gridViewImageId;

public MenuAdapter(Context context, String[] gridViewString, int[] gridViewImageId) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.gridViewImageId = gridViewImageId;
    this.gridViewString = gridViewString;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public String[] getGridViewString() {
    return gridViewString;
}

public int[] getGridViewImageId() {
    return gridViewImageId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = new View(this.mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        text.setText(this.gridViewString[position]);
        image.setImageResource(this.gridViewImageId[position]);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    return view;
}
```

**MenuActivity:**

```
private GridView gridViewMenu;
private MenuAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    String[] gridViewString = {
            getString(R.string.coke),
    } ;

    int[] gridViewImageId = {
            R.drawable.campione,
    };

    this.adapter = new MenuAdapter(this, gridViewString, gridViewImageId);
    this.gridViewMenu = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_menu);
    this.gridViewMenu.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    this.gridViewMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "GridView Item: " + adapter.getGridViewString()[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;
            Intent iback = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainPageActivity.class);
            iback.putExtra(MainPageActivity.EXTRA_SELECTED_VALUE, itemPosition);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, iback);
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

**gridview_layout.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/campione" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_menu.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:numColumns="3" >

</GridView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Menu del bar"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For "Showing nothing" I mean that it just displays the title *Menu del bar*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here change from

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
return 0;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
return gridViewString.length;
}
```

Comment: **THAT'S** what copy and paste can produce... btw great eye mate! I'll mark your answer as possible, thanks